# create and display spark dataframe from simple json file

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

The following simple json DataFrame test works fine when running Spark in local mode. Here is the Scala snippet, but I've successfully got the same thing working in Java and Python as well:

```
sparkContext.addFile(jsonPath)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sparkContext)
val dataFrame = sqlContext.jsonFile(jsonPath)
dataFrame.show()
```

I made sure the jsonPath works from both the driver side as well as the worker side. And I'm calling addFile... The json file is very trivial:

```
[{"age":21,"name":"abc"},{"age":30,"name":"def"},{"age":45,"name":"ghi"}]
```

The exact same code fails when I switch out of local mode and use a separate Spark server with a single master/worker. I've tried this same test in Scala, Java, and Python to try to find some combination that works. They all get basically the same error. The following error is from the  Scala driver program but the Java/Python error messages are nearly identical:

```
15/04/17 18:05:26 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.0.2.15): java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2747)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:1033)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer$Buffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.UTF8.readChars(UTF8.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.UTF8.readString(UTF8.java:208)
```

This is very frustrating. I'm basically trying to get code snippets from the official docs to work.

UPDATE: Thank you Paul for the in depth response. I am getting errors doing the same steps. FYI, earlier I was using a driver program hence the name sparkContext rather than the shell default name of sc. Here is an abbreviated snippet with excess logging removed:

```
➜  spark-1.3.0  ./bin/spark-shell --master spark://172.28.128.3:7077
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_40)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> val dataFrame = sqlContext.jsonFile("/private/var/userspark/test.json")
15/04/20 18:01:06 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.0.2.15): java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2747)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:1033)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer$Buffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.UTF8.readChars(UTF8.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.UTF8.readString(UTF8.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit.readFields(FileSplit.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readObject(ObjectWritable.java:237)
    (...)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 10.0.2.15): java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2747)
```

Comment: I remember reading it doesn't really parse full JSON, i.e. doesn't want the beginning/ending square brackets, and wants one object per line so it can split the file and run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

While I can get your simple example working, I agree that spark can be frustrating...

Here I have spark 1.3.0, built from source with openjdk 8.

Using your file with `spark-shell` or `spark-submit` is failing for different reasons, where possibly the examples/docs is obsolete compared to the released code and needs to be adjusted slightly.

For instance, in spark-shell, `sparkContext` is already available as `sc`, not as `sparkContext`, and there is a similar predefined `sqlContext`.  spark-shell emits INFO messages announcing the creation of these contexts.

For `spark-submit`, I am getting some kind of jar error.  That may be a local issue.

Anyway, it runs fine if I shorten it.  It also doesn't seem to matter, for the purpose of executing this short example, whether the json file has one object per line or not.  For a future test it might be useful to generate a large example and determine if it runs in parallel across the cores and if it needs one object per line (with no commas or top bracket) to accomplish this.

so1-works.sc

```
val dataFrame = sqlContext.jsonFile("/data/so1.json")
dataFrame.show()
```

Output, suppressing INFO, etc. messages...

```
paul@ki6cq:~/spark/spark-1.3.0$ ./bin/spark-shell --master spark://192.168.1.10:7077 <./so1-works.sc 2>/dev/null
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_40-internal)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> 

scala> val dataFrame = sqlContext.jsonFile("/data/so1.json")
dataFrame: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: bigint, name: string]

scala> dataFrame.show()
age name
21  abc 
30  def 
45  ghi 

scala> Stopping spark context.
paul@ki6cq:~/spark/spark-1.3.0$ paul@ki6cq:~/spark/spark-1.3.0$
```

**Odd Note**: Afterwards, I have to execute `reset` to get my linux terminal back to normal.

Ok, so, First, try shortening the example as I have done.

If that doesn't fix it, you can try duplicating my environment.

This might be straightforward as I use docker for the master and worker and have posted the images to the public dockerhub.

**Note to future readers:** My public dockerhub images are not official images for spark and are subject to change or removal.

You need two computers (one running Linux or a docker-compatible OS to host the master and worker within docker containers, the other also preferably running Linux or something with a spark-1.3.0 build) behind a home firewall router device (DLink, Netgrear, etc...). I assume the local network is 192.168.1.*, that 192.168.1.10 and .11 are free, and that the router will route properly, or you know how to make it route properly. You can change these addresses in the run script below.

If you just have one computer, due to particulars of bridging the networking methods I have used here will probably not work properly to communicate back to the host.
It can be made to work, but is a bit more than I'd like to add to an already long posting.

On one Linux computer,  [install docker](https://docs.docker.com/installation/), the [pipework utility](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework), and these shell scripts (adjusting memory granted to spark, editing out the extra workers doesn't seem to be necessary):

./run-docker-spark

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -v
MASTER=$(docker run --name="master" -h master --add-host master:192.168.1.10 --add-host spark1:192.168.1.11 --add-host spark2:192.168.1.12 --add-host spark3:192.168.1.13 --add-host spark4:192.168.1.14 --expose=1-65535 --env SPARK_MASTER_IP=192.168.1.10 -d drpaulbrewer/spark-master:latest)
sudo pipework eth0 $MASTER 192.168.1.10/24@192.168.1.1
SPARK1=$(docker run --name="spark1" -h spark1 --add-host master:192.168.1.10 --add-host spark1:192.168.1.11 --add-host spark2:192.168.1.12 --add-host spark3:192.168.1.13 --add-host spark4:192.168.1.14 --expose=1-65535 --env mem=10G --env master=spark://192.168.1.10:7077 -v /data:/data -v /tmp:/tmp -d drpaulbrewer/spark-worker:latest)
sudo pipework eth0 $SPARK1 192.168.1.11/24@192.168.1.1
```

./stop-docker-spark

```
#!/bin/bash
docker kill master spark1
docker rm master spark1
```

The other linux computer will be your user computer, and needs a build of spark-1.3.0.  Make a /data directory on both computers and install the json file there.  Then run the ./run-docker-spark only once, on the computer that acts as combined host for the containers (like VMs) that will hold the master and worker.   To stop the spark system, use the stop script.  If you reboot, or there's a bad error, you need to run the stop script before the run script will work again.

Check to see that master and worker have paired at http://192.168.1.10:8080

If so, then you should be good to try the spark-shell command line up top.

You don't need these dockerfiles, because the builds are posted on the public dockerhub and downloads are automated in docker run.  But here they are in case you want to see how things are built, the JDKs, maven command, etc.

I start with a common Dockerfile I place in a dir called `spark-roasted-elephant`, since this is a non-hadoop build and the O'Reilley book for hadoop had an elephant on it.  You need a spark-1.3.0 source tarball from the spark website to drop into the directory with the Dockerfile.  This Dockerfile probably doesn't expose enough ports (spark is very promiscuous about its use of ports, whereas docker unfortunately is designed to contain and document the use of ports), and the expose is overridden in the shell scripts that run the master and worker. This will cause some unhappiness if you ask docker to list what is running, because that includes a port list.

```
paul@home:/Z/docker$ cat ./spark-roasted-elephant/Dockerfile
# Copyright 2015 Paul Brewer http://eaftc.com
# License: MIT
# this docker file builds a non-hadoop version of spark for standalone experimentation
# thanks to article at http://mbonaci.github.io/mbo-spark/ for tips
FROM ubuntu:15.04
MAINTAINER drpaulbrewer@eaftc.com
RUN adduser --disabled-password --home /spark spark
WORKDIR /spark
ADD spark-1.3.0.tgz /spark/ 
WORKDIR /spark/spark-1.3.0
RUN sed -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com/www.gtlib.gatech.edu\/pub/' /etc/apt/sources.list > /tmp/sources.list && mv /tmp/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get --yes upgrade \
    && apt-get --yes install sed nano curl wget openjdk-8-jdk scala \
    && echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64" >>/etc/environment \
    && export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m" \
    && ./build/mvn -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package \
    && chown -R spark:spark /spark \
    && mkdir /var/run/sshd
EXPOSE 2222 4040 6066 7077 7777 8080 8081
```

The the master is built from a directory ./spark-master using a dockerfile and a shell script to include into the container.  Here's that dockerfile and shell script.

```
paul@home:/Z/docker$ cat ./spark-master/Dockerfile
FROM drpaulbrewer/spark-roasted-elephant:latest
MAINTAINER drpaulbrewer@eaftc.com
ADD my-spark-master.sh /spark/
USER spark
CMD /spark/my-spark-master.sh

paul@home:/Z/docker$ cat ./spark-master/my-spark-master.sh
#!/bin/bash -e
cd /spark/spark-1.3.0
# set SPARK_MASTER_IP to a net interface address, e.g. 192.168.1.10
export SPARK_MASTER_IP
./sbin/start-master.sh 
sleep 10000d
```

And for the worker:

```
paul@home:/Z/docker$ cat ./spark-worker/Dockerfile
FROM drpaulbrewer/spark-roasted-elephant:latest
MAINTAINER drpaulbrewer@eaftc.com
ADD my-spark-worker.sh /spark/
CMD /spark/my-spark-worker.sh
paul@home:/Z/docker$ cat ./spark-worker/my-spark-worker.sh
#!/bin/bash -e
cd /spark/spark-1.3.0
sleep 10
# dont use ./sbin/start-slave.sh it wont take numeric URL
mkdir -p /Z/data
mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse
chown -R spark:spark /user
su -c "cd /spark/spark-1.3.0 && ./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --memory $mem $master" spark
```

Although by now this post has turned into the answer to "how do I make Dockerfiles for spark?" it isn't intended to be. These Dockerfiles are experimental for me, I do not use them in production and do not vouch for their quality. I disliked a well-regarded source for spark on Docker because they engaged in the lazy practice of chaining a bunch of containers together and it was huge and took forever to download.  Here, there are much fewer layers and the download is smaller.   This is posted not so much as a docker example but so you can determine what is different in your own environment.